# How to get card.io to scan expiration dates? (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, card.io

I've been told by others that the card.io SDK can scan expiration dates in addition to card numbers.  Yet when I integrate it into my iOS 6 iPad project, I'm only able to scan the card number.  Has anyone had success in other implementations?  (i.e. iOS 5, iPhone, etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I'm having the exact same problem. Doesn't look like this is going to be resolved soon, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work at card.io. Newer versions of the card.io SDK (3.x and above) do all the card scanning locally on the client - older versions sent images to our server for scanning. We haven't added expiry scanning to this new version yet, but it's still a better customer experience as it's faster (no waiting for network latency) and more accurate (no more failed reads).

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Is there an older version of the SDK available anywhere for download that I can roll into our project?  It was a client expectation that we scan the expiration dates as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is card.io sdk secure ? Will they are storing credit card info on their server ?