# Card.io SDK gives partial credit card number

Tags: iphone, ios, card.io

I'm currently working with credit-card integration using card.io SDK downloaded from [github](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK).

It works great, but the expiry date and the cvv number has to be entered manually. I searched for that and finds that

> Newer versions of the card.io SDK (3.x and above) doesn't added expiry date
> scanning.-[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078836/756941).

But, the return values shows me

```
Received card info. Number: ••••••••••••xxxx, expiry: 09/2015, cvv: 123.
```

Is it possible to get the full number of the credit-card than getting dots?

Is it possible to download the older version of this SDK for expiration date scanning?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can u get expiry month and year by scanning or manually entered?

Comment: @YogendraPatel, this was 5 years ago. The library might have more limitations in its new versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. The sample code you're probably looking at reads:

```
- (void)userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:(CardIOCreditCardInfo *)info inPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController *)scanViewController {
  // The full card number is available as info.cardNumber, but don't log that!
  NSLog(@"Received card info. Number: %@, expiry: %02i/%i, cvv: %@.", info.redactedCardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv);
  // Use the card info...
  [scanViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note the comment above the NSLog call. What is being logged is `info.redactedCardNumber`. You want `info.cardNumber` instead. See the header files, which are pretty well documented, for more details.

The older version of the SDK is has been publicly deprecated for nearly a year and will be shut down on August 1st, 2013.

Comment: great thanx, started looking at header files document :)

Comment: take a look at my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967889/is-it-possible-to-get-credit-card-type-using-card-io)

Comment: App ask to enter Expiry month and year, Is there any way to scan directly ?? any method missing in it ?? please help.

Comment: hey Josh Bleecher Snyder, i integrate Card.io iOS sdks with my app. use the CardIOView for scanning, not use CardIOPaymentViewController. i get the all info expect CVV number. CVV number is always null for me. is there any reason for that? please help me for that.

Comment: How can u get expiry month and year by scanning or manually entered?