# Is it possible to get credit card type using card.io?

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, card.io

I'm using card.io ios sdk for credit card scanning.

Is it possible to get credit card type(ie, whether it is Amercan Express or Master or visa) using card.io?

What are all the other possible details from credit card that we can get using card.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience of using `card.io`.
But your question got me all curious about this API.
In github, I found it and in there, there is a file: CardIOCreditCardInfo.h

```
// Derived from cardNumber.
// When provided by card.io, cardType will not be CardIOCreditCardTypeUnrecognized or CardIOCreditCardTypeAmbiguous.
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) CardIOCreditCardType cardType;
```

Hope this helps. I am trying to learn this, if it doesnot help you please tell me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CardIOCreditCardInfo *crediCard = [[CardIOCreditCardInfo alloc] init];
crediCard.cardNumber = @"CARD NUMBER";
imageView.image = [CardIOCreditCardInfo logoForCardType:[crediCard cardType]];
```

Comment: Good to see the card type logo from card io library itself.

Answer (score 3):

Josh from card.io here. Take a look at the [CardIOCreditCardInfo header](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CardIO/CardIOCreditCardInfo.h). The `cardType` is derived from the `cardNumber`, and from there you can get localized display strings and logos.

In general, card.io keeps its integration docs to a minimum, just the core product, but exposes extra goodies in the headers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how @Punit's answer is Accepted.. User wants VISA as name, which I achieved with following:

where `info` is object of `CardIOCreditCardInfo` received from `userDidProvideCreditCardInfo` which is `CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate`'s delegate method.

```
NSSTring *cardName = [CardIOCreditCardInfo displayStringForCardType:info.cardType usingLanguageOrLocale:@"en_US"];
```

Since it has public method not instance method

```
/// Convenience method which returns a card type string suitable for display (e.g. "Visa", "American Express", "JCB", "MasterCard", or "Discover").
/// Where appropriate, this string will be translated into the language specified.
/// @param cardType The card type.
/// @param languageOrLocale See CardIOPaymentViewController.h for a detailed explanation of languageOrLocale.
/// @return Card type string suitable for display.

+ (NSString *)displayStringForCardType:(CardIOCreditCardType)cardType usingLanguageOrLocale:(NSString *)languageOrLocale;
```