# Get full card number in human readable formate using card.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, scanning, card.io

i have used card.io to scan my credit card. I got the scanned number but it is showing ************8480 . 
How can i get the exact number. I want to the detect full number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for help. I got the solution.
I have replaced info.redactedCardNumber to info.cardNumber. 
Now it is giving full card number.

```
lblDetail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received card info. Number: %@, expiry: %02lu/%lu, cvv: %@.", info.cardNumber, (unsigned long)info.expiryMonth, (unsigned long)info.expiryYear, info.cvv];
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can refer this same question [Card.io SDK gives partial credit card number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807508/card-io-sdk-gives-partial-credit-card-number)

OR

The sample code you're probably looking at reads:

```
// SomeViewController.m

- (void)cardIOView:(CardIOView *)cardIOView didScanCard:(CardIOCreditCardInfo *)info {
    if (info) {
    // The full card number is available as info.cardNumber, but don't log that!
    NSLog(@"Received card info. Number: %@, expiry: %02i/%i, cvv: %@.", info.redactedCardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv);
    // Use the card info...
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"User canceled payment info");
    // Handle user cancellation here...
  }

  cardIOView.hidden = YES;
}
```

> Write delegate methods to receive the card info or a cancellation:
>   Refer [card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK Documentation](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline; You should explain about `redactedCardNumber`